# Sybase and SQL injection

Tags: sybase-ase

I am maintaining a legacy system that uses Sybase ASE as the database. Because the system is a legacy system, the only way to create an SQL query is string concatenation (prepared statements are not possible*).

Is the below scheme sufficient for preventing SQL injection on "string" columns:

1. Replace all instances of a single quote with two single quotes.
2. Replace all instances of a double quote with two double quotes.

Keep in mind that the \ character is not an escape character in Sybase ASE. Also keep in mind that the columns in the selection clause and the tables in the from clause are static. The only thing that is dynamic is the where clause.

*Stored procs are not possible either, because string concatenation is needed to create the SQL query that calls the stored proc.

Comment: how did  you determine 'prepared statements are not possible'?  'prepared statements' is a capability of the client/application; for as long as I can recall 'prepared statements' is supported by ASE in the form of lightweight procedures (LWPs; think 'temp procs') and is only limited by what the client side API can support; as for the issue regarding SQL injection ... anytime you're concatenating strings you run the risk of SQL injection if you do not (strictly) control the strings you're piecing together

Comment: while [xkcd SQL injection comic](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom) discusses SQL injection for an INSERT, it wouldn't be hard to provide examples for other SQL statements (eg, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT) if you happen to know/guess a bit about how the SQL is being pieced together

Comment: Hi, the client side api can only support sending strings to Sybase. Prepared statements are therefore not possible. But I have just thought of a solution involving stored procs and user roles.  Each client program will call a stored proc and use a user account that entitles it to its assigned stored proc only. This prevents the string calling the stored proc from being escaped. 'exec stroed_Proc param1, param2, param3 [malicous code]' The [malcious code] whatever it does, won't run because the permissions do not entitle it to run.